# Javascript Doesn't Work in Heroku but in Local Environment

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku

My javascript works in local environment but not on Heroku.

The file is "destroy.js.erb" and it is located in view, same as index.html.erb (where javascript is used).

Here are the Heroku logs that I suspect where the error occurred:

```
2014-01-07T03:34:31.980578+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-01-07T03:34:31.980578+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/application-ed404d2f6b226ecfcf36b0b53bc646a7.js"):
2014-01-07T03:34:31.980578+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-01-07T03:34:31.976356 #2]  INFO -- : Started GET "/assets/application-ed404d2f6b226ecfcf36b0b53bc646a7.js" for 24.24.157.128 at 2014-01-07 03:34:31 +0000
2014-01-07T03:34:31.980578+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2014-01-07T03:34:31.977454 #2] FATAL -- : 
2014-01-07T03:34:31.980578+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
```

destroy.js.erb: (JavaScript is called delete user via fadeOut instead of page refresh)

```
$('#<%= dom_id(@user) %>').fadeOut();
```

index.html.erb:

```
<h3>All Users List</h3>

<head>  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script> </head>

    <% @users.each do |user| %>

      <%= div_for user do %>

        <%= link_to "User #{user.firstname} #{user.lastname}", user %>
        <font color='green'><%= user.email %></font>

        <div class="actions">
         <td><%= link_to 'View Detail', user %></td>
         <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(user) %></td>
         <td><%= link_to 'Delete User', user_path(user), method: :delete, remote: true, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %></td>
         <p>
        </div>

      <% end %>

    <% end %>

<%= link_to 'Create New User', new_user_path %>
```

layouts/application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Crud</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: Here is the app: http://sheltered-sea-8479.herokuapp.com/users

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: Use Chrome's Developer tools (or Firebug if you're using Firefox) and see what the request looks like in your local environment. Is it requesting the same path for `application.js`? I suspect it's not, and that may point you towards the right direction.

Comment: Hello! How do I check request path using Firebug? I'm very new to web dev. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't use Firefox but here's the docs: http://getfirebug.com/network

Comment: Nice! I see Firebug shows the application- application-ed404d2f6b226ecfcf36b0b53bc646a7.js cannot be found. But in local, it pulls the js files correctly :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll preface what I'm about to say with I know this idea is like mass destruction for a small problem, but I beat my head against the wall for days with this problem and this was the only way I found to fix it...

Try increasing the `config.assets.version` value in your `config/production.rb` file.  It will expire **all** assets for your app, but it will regenerate the md5 fingerprint for that file as well, and *should* help the app recognize it again.

Example:

Change `config.assets.version = '1.0'` to `config.assets.version = '1.1'`.

**UPDATE**

It sounds like Heroku isn't precompiling your assets for you.  Try to run: `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` then redeploy.  If you're not using `bundler`, you can remove the `bundle exec` from the above command.

Comment: Awesome! You're my hope now. I'll give it a try and report back!

Comment: Let me know if that doesn't work.  I literally spent days on this *exact* problem and this resolved it for me.  Good luck!

Comment: Hmm I see application-ed404d2f6b226ecfcf36b0b53bc646a7.js changed to application-0b975948ea716184c402656fda6196d0.js. But still Firebug shows status 404 not found :/

Comment: Haha! I've been troubleshooting this for 6 hours now. I can't believe this is taking me so long!

Comment: What's your `app/views/layouts/application.*` look like?  Can you add that to the question?

Comment: updated :) I didn't know this file existed. Maybe we're on the right direction!

Comment: I see application-0b975948ea716184c402656fda6196d0.js is now updated to application-413a140e5b5651878805713af3dc0625.js. But Firebug, again, shows status 404 not found on it. I understand precompile puts all javascripts to application.js (thus application-0b975948ea716184c402656fda6196d0.js) then we push it to heroku. However, I have no idea why Firebug says application-0b975948ea716184c402656fda6196d0.js cannot be found!

Comment: The 404 means it's not there, this why I say try the precompile manually to see if that works.

Comment: I found the solution! It turned out that I had to manually include "gem 'rails_12factor'" in my Gemfile, then run Bundle Install, and push to Git, then Heroku. Thanks for your time. I wouldn't have resolved this without your help!